# Multiple transformation Animation Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have applied two animations to two items in compose and one is to alter the size and other is to alter the offset while user clicks on that item. And reverse it when user clicks again.

While the animation is enlarging it feels smooth but when it getting back to original size, I see a glitch. How do I handle this animations in jetpack compose.

```
    val sizeAnimation: Dp by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = if (isExpand.value) 327.dp else 120.dp,
        animationSpec = tween(animationSpeed)
    )
    val offsetAnimation by animateDpAsState(
        targetValue = if (isExpand.value) 100.dp else 0.dp,
        animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = animationSpeed),
    )

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .offset(y = offsetAnimation)
                        .padding(SectionPaddingValues.value)
                        .noRippleClickable {
                         
                            isExpand.value = !isExpand.value
                            
                        },
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                        Image(
                            bitmap = itemBitmap,
                            contentDescription = null,
                            modifier = Modifier.size(sizeAnimation),
                            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                        )
                }
```

I have tried using updateTransition in Jetpack compose. Since it's two items I was not able to find a solution for this yet.